# How can i find the details of a student based on his lowest qualification from a list of all his qualifications

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables, student and qualifications as mentioned below. I have to find the details of all students based on the required fields and the order of the records should be based on his marks , age, highest qualification, lowest qualification and the percentage of his lowest qualifications.

I have tried different queries where i have included all the necessary fields. But suppose if a student has 3 qualifications, the records are multiplied that many number of times.
FOR Ex:

```
Sr.No  Student_ID Highest Qualification Marks
1      001         Grad     SSC        80 
2      001         Grad     HSC        60 
3      001         Grad     Grad       80 
4      002         HSC      SSC        60 
5      002         HSC      HSC        50 
6      003         SSC      SSC        40
```

This is the query which i have tried

```
SELECT std.stud_id, std.dob, std.highest_qual, MIN(std.lowest_qual) , std.marks
FROM student std
LEFT JOIN qualifications qual ON std.stud_id = qual.stud_id 
Where std.fees_paid ='Y'
ORDER BY std.marks, std.dob, std.highest_qual
```

Expected result:

```
001 23-04-1991 Grad SSC 80
002 20-09-1992 HSC  SSC 60
003 13-05-1992 SSC  SSC 40
```

Result from query:  the query returns all the records instead of a single records for each student

```
001 23-04-1991 Grad SSC 80
001 23-04-1991 Grad HSC 60
001 23-04-1991 Grad GRAD 80
002 20-09-1992 HSC  SSC 60
002 20-09-1992 HSC  HSC 60
003 13-05-1992 SSC  SSC 40
```

Comment: Why do you join `qualifications` table if you do not use it in your query?

Comment: i've used left join because later i might have to use multiple fields apart from the ones mentioned above and also include different condition

Comment: And how do you know which qualification is higher? max() and min() would use alphabetical sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you `qualifications` table has some indicator to suggest the rank for a given qualification(say `qual_rank`). If so, you may do

```
select * from
( select s.*, row_number() OVER ( partition by student_id 
       order by q.qual_rank ) as rn
   from student s join qualifications qual ON std.stud_id = qual.stud_id 
) sq where rn = 1;
```

If not, you must define the hierarchy

```
select * from
( select s.*, row_number() OVER ( partition by student_id order by 
                                            CASE qualification WHEN  'SSC'  THEN 1 
                                                               WHEN  'HSC' THEN 2
                                                               WHEN  'Grad' THEN 3
                                                        END 
                                                  ) as rn
from student s) sq where rn = 1;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d2f78e43dd1b79d7685fad36c16beee6)

Comment: assume that the 2nd candidate has home schooled and directly has his lowest qualification in records as HSC instead of SSC. Would that make any difference to the records?

Comment: @PrajaktaKalghatgi : Have you tried using it? What do you expect to see in that case SSC or HSC?

Comment: if the highest lowest qualification is HSC then HSC should be displayed for that student and SSC for other students.

Comment: @PrajaktaKalghatgi : It will work as expected, see [**this**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e4881fc91413a987c70dbe4d492288fb)  and note the result for `student_id` 3.  Why don't you  try and let me know if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the table structure to be like this and I have mentioned the query for this structure.

```
CREATE TABLE student(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);

INSERT INTO student VALUES(1,'Tom');
INSERT INTO student VALUES(2,'Lucy');
INSERT INTO student VALUES(3,'Frank');
INSERT INTO student VALUES(4,'Jane');
INSERT INTO student VALUES(5,'Robert');

CREATE TABLE Qualifications(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, qualification_text text, qualification_level integer);

INSERT INTO Qualifications VALUES(1,'SSC',1);
INSERT INTO Qualifications VALUES(2,'HSC',2);
INSERT INTO Qualifications VALUES(3,'Grad',3);



CREATE TABLE StudentQualifications(student_id integer, qualification_id integer, marks float);

INSERT INTO StudentQualifications VALUES(1,1,80);
INSERT INTO StudentQualifications VALUES(1,2,90);
INSERT INTO StudentQualifications VALUES(1,3,90);
INSERT INTO StudentQualifications VALUES(2,1,75);
INSERT INTO StudentQualifications VALUES(3,1,70);

SELECT result.Name, highest.qualification_text, highest_marks.marks,lowest.qualification_text,lowest_marks.marks FROM
(SELECT Std.name AS Name,Std.Id AS stud_id, MAX(q.qualification_level) AS 
highest,MIN(q.qualification_level) AS lowest
FROM 
student std
LEFT JOIN 
StudentQualifications sq
ON 
std.id = sq.student_id
INNER JOIN
Qualifications q
ON
sq.qualification_id = q.Id
GROUP BY std.Name, std.Id) result
INNER JOIN
Qualifications highest 
ON
highest.qualification_level = result.highest
INNER JOIN
Qualifications lowest
ON
lowest.qualification_level = result.lowest
INNER JOIN
StudentQualifications highest_marks
ON
highest.id = highest_marks.qualification_id
AND
result.stud_id = highest_marks.student_id 
INNER JOIN
StudentQualifications lowest_marks
ON
lowest.id = lowest_marks.qualification_id
AND
result.stud_id = lowest_marks.student_id;
```

You might need to change INNER JOINS to LEFT JOINS based on the data and output you prefer.

Comment: this query will only result in the highest and lowest qualification. How can i get the marks of lowest qualification?

Comment: You can just edit the last query to join with StudentQualifications again to get the marks:

Comment: I have edited the answer now. Hope this works for you